# Griddb Missing Files on PHP Client on Centos 7

Tags: php, centos, swig, pcre, griddb

I have attempted several times to install the PHP client for Griddb. I used both the manual source and package via Composer. When I try to compile the client, I get header files php.h, and zend_interface.h missing. I replaced that with a file, "php_griddb_php_client.h" and this worked. However, the next error I received was that "zend_interface.h" was missing. I suspect more header files and other files may be missing.

[Missing files in the compilation of PHP client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWHJr.png)

I have searched my whole server for these files when downloading the client, and I have also explored the Github repository. In either case, these files are not present and not present in previous branches.

Could the client Makefile be just wrong, or will the header files come from somewhere else? The process I used to install the client manually, from scratch successfully, the order was:

Install Centos 7.
Install PHP 7.4.29.
Install #Griddb.
Install PCRE (for Centos and Swig).
Install the C client for PHP & Swig.

I then downloaded the PHP client, first manually, then using the Composer package. In both cases, the header files mentioned above are missing. I searched my whole server and the GitHub repository (+ associated branches), and these header files are not present.

PHP itself works, and the C and Java clients work for Griddb. It just appears to be an issue with the PHP client under Centos.

Can anyone help?

Comment: As a follow on the above, I would suggest that Zend is actually part of PHP as an extension, and not Griddb itself.  Also, the missing php.h file also looks like an unrelated  griddb issue. As I stated previously, PHP works fine, but maybe it needs the Zend libraries for PHP, and there appears to be a lack of information on this on the Griddb site. Maybe they should be included as part of the PHP client, or the swig/pcre applications?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the php-devel library. can you try installing that and see if it works for you?

Comment: Thanks for this! After checking, I found that I do indeed already have the PHP development libraries included, but it appears they are not in the usual place i.e.:

/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/include/php/Zend

This means I will need to amend the Makefile to point to the relevant areas for the include files. I will be able to see if this works by next week,. If you have anything further to add that would be appreciated, Kind regards, Andrew Carr.